# Pycharm - Glove-Python Install Failing with Exit Status 2

Tags: python, installation, pycharm, stanford-nlp

I am trying to install glove-python ( https://github.com/maciejkula/glove-python ) using PyCharm to install it on my VENV using pip.

I get the error using pip

```
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 
14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 
'c:\users\f00ly\pycharmprojects\untitled\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, 
tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\F00LY\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-p0hrtvft\\glove- 
python\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\F00LY\\AppData\\Local\\
Temp\\pip-install-p0hrtvft\\glove-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open) 
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 
'"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\F00LY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-_9u3p7yz\install- 
record.txt' --s
ingle-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 
'c:\users\f00ly\pycharmprojects\untitled\venv\include\site\python3.7\glove-python' Check the logs for 
full command output.
```

I get the error using python setup.py install

```
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

No idea how to resolve this. I've confirmed the cl.exe file is in that folder that it lists.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open issue for glove-python: [Unable to install glove_python in virtual environment](https://github.com/maciejkula/glove-python/issues/107)

In short, the steps to install on windows, python<=3.6  are:

1. Download and unzip [mingw-w64](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/4.8.1/64-bit/threads-posix/seh/)
2. Add the `bin\` directory to your PATH
3. Install an up-to-date version of `libpython`
4. Clone this repository and move into its root directory
   (`glove-python`)
5. Run `pip install .`